# Distribution of eigenvectors of random matrices and link with the components of the matrix

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, eigenvector

Let $M$ be a real symmetric matrix of size $N$ with its components $M_{ij}$ following a normal distribution centered around 0.

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$ be an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$\sum_j M_{ij}x_j=\lambda x_i$$

I know that in that case the eigenvectors of different eigenvalues are independent from one another. However:

- Is there any universality property regarding the distribution of the elements of the eigenvectors? If we want normalised eigenvectors I suppose that each entry of the eigenvector must have a variance that scales with $1/N$?
- Is there any known relation between the matrix elements and the corresponding eigenvector elements? I am particularly interested in the correlation $\langle M_{ij}x_j\rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• For large $N$ the elements of an eigenvector have independent Gaussian distributions with zero mean and variance $1/N$.

• To find $\mathbb{E}[M_{ij}x_j]$ I decompose the matrix $M$ into eigenvalues and eigenvectors,
$$M_{ij}=\sum_{k} O_{ki}\lambda_k O_{kj},$$
with an orthogonal matrix $O$. Then
$$\mathbb{E}[M_{ij}x_j]=\sum_{k} \mathbb{E}[O_{ki}\lambda_k O_{kj}O_{1j}].$$
This vanishes because eigenvectors and eigenvalues are independent, and $\mathbb{E}[\lambda_k]=0$.

Comment: How can I show the first point? Is it still the case when the elements are not independent anymore but have some correlation?

Comment: If the elements of the matrix are correlated, can the eigenvectors and eigenvalues still be independent?

Comment: (1) The first point is the Porter-Thomas distribution of the Gaussian Orthogonal Ensemble (GOE), it holds only for $N\gg 1$ and only if you are considering the joint distribution of a small subset $n\ll N$ of the elements. (2) The second point holds exactly for any $N$ in the GOE, so if the elements of $M$ are uncorrelated; if they are correlated, it holds for $N\gg 1$ because the GOE is reached in that limit.